# How to grow the size of the tree control when the child item count increases

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I have a scrolled window and I am placing multiple tree control in the scrolled window. When ever i add more child items to the root of any treectrl it creates a scrollwindow to make sure all child will be accessible. What i need to achieve is increase in size allocated to tree ctrl instead of scrolled window. How do i achieve this

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no automatic method that can do this. You will have to implement it manually, i.e. when you are done with the insertions you explicitly invoke a resize of the control. Here the C++ code snippet, taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291848/wxgrid-how-to-fit-the-outer-window-around-a-small-grid)

```
treeCtrl->InvalidateBestSize();
treeCtrl->SetClientSize(treeCtrl->GetBestSize());
```

The Python version should not be very different – probably the `->` operators will have to be replaced by dots.

Comment: Thanks  alberto for your response. I solved this problem with treeCtrl->setMaxSize(wxDefalultSize) command. This will resize the treectrl winow as and when the number of children is increased.

Comment: OK, though my answer did not fit your case I am happy to know that your issue is solved. Maybe your solution will be useful for my future projects too.